# How many different groups of 12 are being in an average of 1.7 groups?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, dimensional-analysis

If I have $10$ million people, how do I calculate how many different groups of $12$ with each person being in an average of $1.7$ groups?

Comment: Showing your attempts helps others understand your level of knoweledge and sometimes clarifies your request.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are $10$ million people, each of which are in on average $1.7$ groups each.  Suppose that each person has a group membership identification card.  Then that is to say, each person owns on average $1.7$ group membership identification cards.

If you multiply these numbers, you get $10$ million people$\cdot 1.7\frac{\text{cards}}{\text{person}}=17$ million group identification cards.  But since groups are all of size $12$, you can group up the identification cards into batches of twelve.

As such, there are $17$ million cards $\cdot \frac{1~\text{group}}{12~\text{cards}} \approx 1.417$ million groups.  (specifically $1~416~666$ groups or $1~416~667$ groups depending on how you like to round)